# Problem while creating a Record (CRUD)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to save data in my Database using Rail 3 but i could not do that.an
Error occured like this:
**NoMethodError in Vorlesungs#new**

in my Controller:

```
class VorlesungsController < ApplicationController
  def new
         @vorlesung=Vorlesung.new
  end

 def create
    @vorlesung=Vorlesung.create(params[:vorlesung])
    if @vorlesung.save
       @status_message = 'Student inserted successfully.'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

and my View:

```
    <%= form_for @vorlesung do |v| %>
    Name : <%= v.text_field :Name %>    <br>
    Name de Professur : <%= v.text_field :Leiter_name %><br>
    <%= v.submit 'Speicher'%>

<% end %>
```

when i changed  Form_for into
  **<%= form_for @vorlesung do |v| %>**
an error like this occured:
   NoMethodError in Vorlesungs#new
when Form_for remains as:
  **<%= form_for :vorlesung do |v| %>**
after clicking my submit button only the content of textboxes deleted 
and no other effect.Thank you very much for your help

that is my full error message:

```
NoMethodError in Vorlesungs#new

Showing /home/babak/Management/app/views/vorlesungs/new.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `vorlesungs_path' for #<#<Class:0xb5f55cc0>:0xb5f54f00>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @vorlesung do |v| %>
2:     Name : <%= v.text_field :Name %>    <br>
3:     Name de Professur : <%= v.text_field :Leiter_name %><br>
4:     <%= v.submit 'Speicher'%>
```

and it is my route file:

```
Management::Application.routes.draw do
 # get "vorlesungs/Show"
  root :to => 'vorlesungs#Show'
  match 'vorlesungs/new' =>'vorlesungs#new'
end
```

Comment: What line is the `NoMethodError` pointing to?

Comment: Try to generate a scaffold and compare with your actual controller 'rails g scaffold test name:string'

Comment: can you post your routes.rb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined a create action in your routes.

Instead of

```
 # get "vorlesungs/Show"
  root :to => 'vorlesungs#Show'
  match 'vorlesungs/new' =>'vorlesungs#new'
```

add

```
resources :vorlesungs
```

A good guide on this is to be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Tanx,I did it but everythings remains :(

Comment: Hmm. Can you post the full error in your question. Also, your model fields are capitalised (:Name rather than :name) which doesn't follow convention. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you mark,Would you please tell me what make   resources :vorlesungs

Comment: It defines all the crud routes. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default